# ".hasSuffix" not working in 3ed Party Swift Editor

Tags: swift, ibm-cloud

i am using the following website (https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net) to try my swift code out because I don't have a mac yet. I developed the following very simple calculator on this website and want it to print the result as an Int instead of a Double. I don't know why it doesn't work. My best guess is that it has to do with the fact that it is running on a 3ed party client. I would appreciate every kind of help.

```
var number1: Double = 2
var number2: Double = 3

func Add() -> Double {
return number1 + number2    
}

func Dif() -> Double {
return number1 - number2    
}

func Mul() -> Double {
return number1 * number2    
}

func quo() -> Double {
return number1 / number2    
}

var result = Add()
let result2 = String(result)
if  result2.hasSuffix(".0") {
    print(Int:result2)
}
else {
    print(result2)
}
```

Comment: Did you `import Foundation`?

Comment: `print(Int:result2)` does not compile.

Comment: print(Int(result)) is probably what he means